# Error messages during boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd, cgroup

I recently applied some software updates to my 18.04 LTS install, and I now see the following during restart:

```
$ cat /var/log/boot.log  Scanning for Btrfs filesystems UBUNTU: clean, 700970/30883840 files, 21610032/123523840 blocks [  OK  ] Found device /sys/subsystem/net/devices/br0. [  OK  ] Started ifup for br0.
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service... [  OK  ]
         Starting Virtualization daemon...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting containerd container runtime...
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server... [  OK  ] 
         Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting Message of the Day...
         Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting GNOME Display Manager... 

         [  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of root. 
         [FAILED] Failed to start Session c2 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c2.scope' for details. 
         [FAILED] Failed to start Session c7 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c7.scope' for details. 
         [FAILED] Failed to start Session c4 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c4.scope' for details. 
         [FAILED] Failed to start Session c3 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c3.scope' for details. 
         [  OK  ] Started Session c11 of user root.
         Starting User Manager for UID 0... 
         [FAILED] Failed to start Session c5 of user root. See ....
```

systemctl has the following to say:

```
$ systemctl status session-c2.scope
● session-c2.scope - Session c2 of user root
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-c2.scope; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: failed (Result: resources)

Apr 21 15:50:53 dell systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Apr 21 15:50:53 dell systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Apr 21 15:50:53 dell systemd[1]: Failed to start Session c2 of user root.
```

Other useful info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dell 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/version_signature 
Ubuntu 4.15.0-96.97-generic 4.15.18
```

And this:

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

I don't know enough about cgroups to make changes on my own...looking for help in trying to understand what's going on here.

Thank you so much for any help, please!

EDIT: As requested:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="locale=en_US intel_iommu=on"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

EDIT 2: After adding "systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=true" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (and update-grub followed by reboot):

```
$ grep cgroup /proc/filesystems
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Thank you @Raffa for reading the post. Edited as you suggested.

Comment: This _may_ be applicable, but didn't work for me: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3388#issuecomment-599679387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have Docker installed. Docker makes use of cgroups and it seems you have **[unified cgroup hierarchy (a.k.a. cgroups-v2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/cgroups.7.html#cgroups%20version%202)** enabled. As far as I know cgroups-v2 has not been adopted by Ubuntu yet and most importantly it can not be enabled alongside with cgroups-v1, they both do the same job and this can result in the errors you see.

I would suggest an easy fix based on [systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemd.1.html) which is to add the `systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=true` option to your `/etc/default/grub` file like so:

Open the `/etc/default/grub` file in an editor by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

change it to look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=true"
```

Then, save the file and close the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then update GRUB by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reset systemd's failed units by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

Then reboot your system.

---

**Notice:**

It is not unusual for a session creation to fail once or more times during boot as long as it succeeds eventually. which appears to be the situation in your case looking into these messeges:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Session c2 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c2.scope' for details. 
[FAILED] Failed to start Session c7 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c7.scope' for details. 
[FAILED] Failed to start Session c4 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c4.scope' for details. 
[FAILED] Failed to start Session c3 of user root. See 'systemctl status session-c3.scope' for details. 
[  OK  ] Started Session c11 of user root.
```

So if no other issues are present with your system, then these messages can happen sometimes and be normal. You seem to be using Docker and these scopes/sessions mean logins ie. each user including the login manager needs a separate session/scope and they might fail at first then retried later. Bottom-line is if everything is working fine, you can ignore these messages.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I see the same error messages during boot (and in boot.log). Regardless, though, thank you for taking the time to investigate.

Comment: @AlgorithmsGuy Please add the output of `grep cgroup /proc/filesystems` to your question

Comment: @AlgorithmsGuy Try `sudo systemctl reset-failed` then reboot and see how it goes.

Comment: No luck :-(   Same errors:

$ systemctl status session-c3.scope
● session-c3.scope - Session c3 of user root
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-c3.scope; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: failed (Result: resources)

Apr 21 19:51:39 dell systemd[1]: session-c3.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Apr 21 19:51:39 dell systemd[1]: session-c3.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Apr 21 19:51:39 dell systemd[1]: Failed to start Session c3 of user root.

Comment: @AlgorithmsGuy If no other issues are present with your system, then these messages can happen sometimes and be normal. You seem to be using Docker and these scopes mean logins ie. each session including the login manager needs a separate session/scope and they might fail at first then retried later. Bottom-line is if everything is working fine, you can ignore these messages.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am (was) worried because these are new, and didn't show up until I decided to follow along with whatever software updater was asking me to do.
Thank you.

Comment: @AlgorithmsGuy No problem and no worry as I said it is normal for a session to fail and start later and your output shows that `[  OK  ] Started Session c11 of user root.` so the session was started after all.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer -- thank you.
Note, however, that these error messages don't show up sometimes...they *_always_* show up during boot/startup (which is not needed frequently, but disturbing to see nonetheless).